python programming, what was a mistake with this code
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class PermissionSystemGUI:
def init(self, root):
self.root = root
self.root.title("Permission System GUI")
    # Create tabs
    self.tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
    self.user_tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.role_tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
    self.permission_tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)

    self.tab_control.add(self.user_tab, text="Users")
    self.tab_control.add(self.role_tab, text="Roles")
    self.tab_control.add(self.permission_tab, text="Permissions")

    self.tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    # User tab
    self.user_label = ttk.Label(self.user_tab, text="Users:")
    self.user_label.pack()
    self.user_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.user_tab)
    self.user_listbox.pack()
    self.create_user_button = ttk.Button(self.user_tab, text="Create User", command=self.create_user)
    self.create_user_button.pack()

    # Role tab
    self.role_label = ttk.Label(self.role_tab, text="Roles:")
    self.role_label.pack()
    self.role_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.role_tab)
    self.role_listbox.pack()
    self.create_role_button = ttk.Button(self.role_tab, text="Create Role", command=self.create_role)
    self.create_role_button.pack()

    # Permission tab
    self.permission_label = ttk.Label(self.permission_tab, text="Permissions:")
    self.permission_label.pack()
    self.permission_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.permission_tab)
    self.permission_listbox.pack()
    self.assign_permission_button = ttk.Button(self.permission_tab, text="Assign Permission", command=self.assign_permission)
    self.assign_permission_button.pack()

def create_user(self):
    # Create a new user
    user_name = input("Enter user name: ")
    # Add user to listbox
    self.user_listbox.insert(tk.END, user_name)

def create_role(self):
    # Create a new role
    role_name = input("Enter role name: ")
    # Add role to listbox
    self.role_listbox.insert(tk.END, role_name)

def assign_permission(self):
    # Assign permission to role
    role_name = input("Enter role name: ")
    permission_name = input("Enter permission name: ")
    # Add permission to listbox
    self.permission_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"{role_name}: {permission_name}")

if name == "main":
root = (link unavailable)()
gui = PermissionSystemGUI(root)
root.mainloop()

Ask Ubuntu is about question and support on using Ubuntu and its flavors. Your question is not related to Ubuntu at all, the problem  may arise on any operating system capable of running Python and the Tk module. You may want to consider raising your question at Stack Overflow, which is a platform dedicated to coding questions.
